# The approve, reject or improve edit option makes the Rendered output window appear on the right

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits

The approve, reject or improve edit option in a post makes the Rendered output window to appear on the right instead of the usual way of appearing on left. This forces us to scroll to the right to see it fully.

[image]

[image]

I tried in Chrome and Edge browsers (updated), got the same output in both.

---

Edit: (Reg. display size) The display size is default, but it still occurs.

[image]

Comment: No repro on SO. Do you have some special display settings? Extremely large or so?

Comment: No repro on MSE.

Comment: I have this same bug on FireFox and it only happens on SO. I haven't been able to figure out why (started around 2-3 weeks ago). On all other sites the suggested edit compressed the 2 parts nicely to fit on the screen, but on SO it overflows considerably. I usually use 120% zoom on my laptop, to avoid useless margins, I tried adjusting but it still happens. It's not difficult to reproduce, it happens 90% just from having several tabs open, but sometimes with a freshly launched browser and 1 single tab it doesn't happen. I would have posted this earlier, thought the error was on my side.

Comment: No repro on SO, using FF on MAC, not on light and not on dark mode. What is the size and resolution of your screen? I can't repro on a large monitor, or on the monitor of my 13" MBA.

Comment: @Luuklag Resolution : 1920 X 1080, size: 15.6" in laptop.. Currently I'm away from my desktop, not sure about its size, but same resolution

Comment: @rene Shall I vote to close or delete this post?

Comment: @Ak. that is up to you but if you still can somehow/sometimes reproduce this problem I wouldn't mind if you keep it up and open so either an answer can be posted that solves the issue or a user shows up with the same issue and the both of you can work out the commonality between each local setup. If you now delete it we have nothing to refer to, unless I remember this question and then ask a mod to find it again for me if a future report comes in.